# Ruby resque background CSV import does not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, redis, resque

I am trying to import a CSV file using a background job with resque.  It appears to run but nothing happens.   The import worked fine when I was not using resque (I am using resque because some imports are large and I want to move to a background job, for testing its a small 2 row csv)

Any help is super appreciated, thank you very much!
(also im a beginner so please dumb down any help :))

inventories_controller.rb  :

```
  def import
    Resque.enqueue(Inventorycsvimport, params[:file], current_user.id)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Inventory import job started."
  end
```

worker JOB  inventorycsvimport.rb  :

```
class Inventorycsvimport
  @queue = :Inventorycsvimport
  def self.perform()
    Inventory.destroy_all(user_id: current_user.id)
    Inventory.import(params[:file], current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Import Class inventory.rb  :

```
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

  def self.import(file, user_id)
    allowed_attributes = [ "user_id", "id","description","part_number","price","created_at","updated_at", "alternate_part_number", "condition_code", "qty", "mfg_code", "serial_number", "part_comments"]
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      inventory = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      inventory.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
      inventory.user_id = user_id
      inventory.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
      when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error I get in the JOB:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging step by step and tried where it fails actually. Please provide your findings on same

Comment: How do you get `current_user` inside the job? Does not seem to be passed in as a parameter. Might be that it's `nil` inside the job. In that case your validations fail because `inventory` requires a valid `user` in which case it does not get saved and nothing happens (except you should have seen that in logs since it would produce `ValidationError` Because of `save!`

Comment: @Kkulikovskis I changed the controller to: def import
    Resque.enqueue(Inventorycsvimport, params[:file], current_user.id)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Inventory import job started."
  end  and now I get Exception
NameError
Error
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Inventorycsvimport:Class

Comment: @Kkulikovskis I updated my original post with the code and the error from job - thanks for your help!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check Sidekiq documentation. As far as I know, all passed in parameters are available inside the job through `options` hash. so when passing parameter you need to receive it on the other end somehow.

Try this in controller:

```
  def import
    Resque.enqueue(Inventorycsvimport, file: params[:file], user_id: current_user.id)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Inventory import job started."
  end
```

and this in your job:

```
  def self.perform
    Inventory.destroy_all(user_id: options[:user_id])
    Inventory.import(options[:file], options[:user_id])
  end
```

Your code does not make a lot of sense (I advise some programming tutorials (codecademy.com could be a good start), because you are trying to use variables in different scopes. The `current_user` that you have in your controller is not a magical variable that you can access anywhere. It comes from helper methods defined under `ActionController::Base` or `ApplicationController` classes from which your controller class inherits.

Since your Job classes have nothing to do with the controller classes, it can't access any of controller's methods or variables directly. Thus you have such options as `parameters` when defining methods, which allows you to pass these variables across different classes and scopes.

What might be confusing in this case is the job's `perform` method, where you do not have to declare `options` as an argument, because it is using `ActiveJob` (or plain `Sidekiq`) class under the hood which has the same method with `options` hash defined as an argument. the `file:` and `user_id:` are just a pretty thing in Ruby called `named arguments`. So you do not have to constantly check the parameter order, when using a function. But srsly, I suggest taking some tutorials and you will get this in no time :)